# Javascript to pre-select textarea on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have a page that has a textarea, when the page is loaded, I want to pre-select the textarea(like twitter.com does), so the user does not have to click on it. Do you know how to do that?

Previously thanks!

Rodrigo Alves Vieira.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#text-area-id').focus();
});
```

check here: http://jsfiddle.net/jxrS7/