# javascript select text in textarea onload

Tags: javascript, html

How do I automatically select the text that is in a textarea when the page loads using JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript to pre-select textarea on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646004/javascript-to-pre-select-textarea-on-page-load)

Comment: @Neal thanks for the link. I didn't see that question.

Comment: Neal's link it's based off jQuery

Comment: @kjy112 yes, I know. I do like your method better. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/V85mC/)

You can do it this way:

HTML:

```
<textarea id='mytext'>Testing 1 2 3</textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
 window.onload = document.getElementById('mytext').select();
```

Where mytext is your textarea

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Textarea:
    <textarea rows="3" id="txtarea"  style="width:200px" >This text you can select all by clicking here </textarea>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById('txtarea').focus();
        document.getElementById('txtarea').select();

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the onload function of your body, place a call to the select function of your textarea...

HTML:

```
<body onload='highlightTextArea()'>
    <textarea id='myTextArea'>Hello World!</textarea>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var highlightTextArea = function (){
    document.getElementById('myTextArea').select();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this is the answer posted on the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646004/javascript-to-pre-select-textarea-on-page-load):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#text-area-id').focus();
});
check here: http://jsfiddle.net/jxrS7/
```

Comment: you need to say: jQuery!