# Preselect text input on page load

Tags: javascript, html, input

I don't want the user to have to click the first text box to write on it. When the page is loaded, I want the text input to be preselected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript select text in textarea onload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679932/javascript-select-text-in-textarea-onload)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the autofocus attribute inside your html element.

In this example, you can see the "First name" input has autofocus, and it will be automatically selected when the page loads, so the user can type straight away:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" autofocus><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The autofocus attribute, of the input tag, is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

Answer (score 5):

It's very simple. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yyu8/).

HTML

```
<input id="box" value="text" />
```

JavaScript

```
window.onload = document.getElementById('box').select();
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic example using [javascript HTMLElement.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.focus)

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setFocus() {
            document.getElementById('txtTwo').focus();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="setFocus();">
        <input id="txtOne" type="text" />
        <br/>
        <input id="txtTwo" type="text" />
</body>
```